# VBA Excel - Coloring eacht cell in a row that contains a value based on the value of another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working on a macro that does a few different things and I am stuck now on the last part of the process.

I have a table and one column beside that table which indicates the color the values of the table should be in. To make it clear what I mean I am attaching this picture:

[image: What I currently have]

Now, as you can see, there are entries in column O which indicate in which color the entries in B:N should be. For example: O3's value is r. This means that C3:E3 should be colored red. Here is how it should look like after the macro has done it's work:

[image: What it should look like in the end]

As you can see it is crucial that the macro only colors those cells in the row which actually have a value/any value. Empty cells should not be colored.

Any help in this regard would be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this...

```
Sub ApplyInteriorColor()
Dim rng As Range
Dim lr As Long, i As Long
Dim clr As Long
clr = vbRed
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("B3:N" & lr).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
If lr > 2 Then
    For i = 3 To lr
        Set rng = Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, "N"))
        If Application.CountA(rng) > 0 And Cells(i, "O") <> "" Then
            Select Case Cells(i, "O").Value
                Case "r'"
                    clr = vbRed
                Case "b"
                    clr = vbBlue
                Case "y"
                    clr = vbYellow
            End Select
            rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 3).Interior.Color = clr
        End If
    Next i
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much.